# adding an object of address to an array of addresses in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

lets say I have the following Model:

```js
const User = mongoose.model('user', {
    addresses: [
        {
            address_name: {
                type: String,
            },
            country: {
                type: String,
        }
    ]
})
```

then in my Rest Api service I call User and update the address of a user.

```js
User.updateOne({
  "_id": user._id
}, {
  $push: {
    "addresses": {
      "address_name": A,
      "country": CountryA
    },
    {
      "address_name": B,
      "country": CountryB
    }
  }
})
```

So at first addresses array is empty and then I add some addresses. So the logic should be like pushing object of address to addresses array.
Its not working with my way right now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `$push` in combination with `$each` in this case. That is when you have an array of multiple objects to be pushed at once.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({
    "_id": user._id
}, {
    $push: {
        "addresses": {
            $each: [{
                "address_name": "A",
                "country": "CountryA"
            }, {
                "address_name": "B",
                "country": "CountryB"
            }]
        }
    }
})
```

---

[Use $each with $push Operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#use-each-with-push-operator).

---

If it was only one object at a time then:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({
    "_id": user._id
}, {
    $push: {
        "addresses": {
            "address_name": "A",
            "country": "CountryA"
        }
    }
})
```

[Append a Value to an Array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#append-a-value-to-an-array).

Comment: Its not working. No error but only one and also multiple object are not added to array in Db

Comment: What do you mean, so only one object is being pushed? Note that `address_name` and `country` has to be a `String` according to your model such as `"CountryA"` etc. Also try using `findOneAndUpdate`. Edited the answer.